# Pump motor fails to start when connected to a low frequency inverter via a long wire

Tags: capacitor, inverter, cables, ac-motor

I've been struggling with a submersible pump showing unreliable behaviour when connected through a long cable to a low frequency inverter.

- The pump is used only once a week to fill up 3 5000 L tanks. It is not permanently connected to an electrical supply and it does not have a float switch.
- The pump in question is a 1000 W submersible pump.
- The pump is connected to its control box via an 10 m, 12 AWG (2.0 mm diameter), 3-lead cable. Ground cable is absent, seemingly due to whoever installed the system could not find a 4 lead cable and omitted the ground connection as the cable available is a 3 lead, but everything else is connected as the diagram shows.
- The control box contains a 50 uF capacitor a switch and a thermo-switch.

[image]

The current property's owner installed a 5 kW Growatt, pure sine-wave, split phase, low frequency inverter to supply the property, which is equipped with two relatively large iron-core output transformers.
Since this became the new setup, there have been repeated attempts to run the pump from the house's outlets, so that the current connections are:

- Outlets are 12 m away from the inverter via 12 AWG (2.0 mm diameter) cables.
- The pump is connected to the outlet through a 35 m 12 AWG extension.
- This totals 47 m of 12 AWG cables from the INVERTER to the CONTROL BOX with the capacitor, and from the control with capacitor to the pump there's the 10 m of 12 AWG cable.

[image]

The system was running fine for about 5 years when once a week it was run from an 8 kW gasoline generator. Since switching to the current long-cable, inverter setup, the pump would fail to start about 20% of times. As time went on the failure-to-start scenario increased to about 100%, and the pump would eventually start only after repeated attempts. The users in question would turn on the pump and wait until one of two things happened:

- The thermo-switch would go off after about 15 s.
- Eventually the pump would start.

In any case, once the pump started, the thermo-switch would go off after about 10 min. of running time.

In desperation tried at some point adding an extra 50 uF in parallel with the first (100 uF total). This managed to "fix" the start-up problem, the pump was actually starting 100% of the time. Alas, the thermo-switch would go off after about some 10 minutes as before.

At some point, in order to carry out some maintenance on the pump, it was pulled up from the well. At this point it was started within a small water tank while being connected to the house's outlet (12 m from inverter to control box + 10 m from control box to pump) and using the correct 50 uF capacitor. The pump would start normally, although due to the test tank being too small, it was not possible to test whether the thermo-switch would go off or not.

[image]

After having the recoil starter rope of the generator repaired, the pump was tested with its former setup, with the correct 50 uF capacitance for the motor.
The result was the pump would start normally, only having 10 m of cable between control box and pump, and 0.4 m between control box and generator. The thermo-switch did not go off --thankfully-- after some 20 minutes of running time although it was getting very hot to the touch.

Some extra data:

- When the inverter was running only a 100 W fridge and a Starlink modem (20-75 W per specification), it displayed 157 W, 206 VA (0.76) as its load.
- When the inverter was running only a starlink modem with minimal network activity the load was 56 W, 115 VA (0.49).
- When the pump was run --successfully started with the double capacitance trick-- the figures were 207 W, 208 VA (0.99).

So I, not being an electrical engineer, am having problems making sense of all this data.
Inductive loads are supposed to be problematic reactive loads, causing problems like a decrease in the power factor, which, if I understand correctly, incurs in losses in the transmission lines (and perhaps the output transformers of the inverter), but then the inverter is showing a theoretical 0.99 PF when the pump runs, which is supposed to be good (even assuming a high inaccuracy in the inverter's measurements, it's much better than the fridge's 0.6).
From what I read on the internet, low power factor is supposed to cause inefficiency in the transmission system, but then the pump was showing a lot of problems while showing a high PF as measured by the inverter.
Moreover, using online calculators (can they be trusted?) the voltage drop for 47 m of 12 AWG cable was calculated to be 2.45 V line to neutral (there's no multi-meter available at the property to carry out actual measurements). If this calculation is to be trusted, a 2.45 V drop in the wire hardly seems to be enough for the pump's failure to start.
I also wonder how a wire's small voltage drop can interact with the capacitors so that 50 uF fails to start the pump while 100 uF works. I know the 12 AWG wire is supposed not to be thick enough, but I fail to see why and how it should matter that much with a reactive load (the 50 versus 100 uF thing, and thermo-switch blowing). In the worst case, I'd expect the wire itself to heat it it's resistance was to high but this was not the case, while the thermo-switch did indeed heat up.

At first, my guess was "it must be something to do with the inverter's switching frequency" only to have my speculation shattered by the fact of the inverter actually being low frequency.

Comment: You are assuming 2.45V based on full-load.  Starting current could be 5-8 times normal full-load current making voltage drop across wire larger.  Napkin calculations give me 20V voltage drop at start.

Comment: "The current property's owner installed a 5000KW Growatt, pure sine-wave, split phase, low frequency inverter". "The system was running fine for about 5 years when once a week it was run from an 8000KW gasoline generator". Do you mean 5 kW inverter and 8 kW gasoline generator?

Comment: vu2nan yep thanks for noting this. I edited it already 

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Thanks. That would explain the failure to start issue. Any ideas why'd the thermo-switch would go off after a while only with the longer cable?

Answer (score 2):

You have 12 + 35 + 10 = 57m × 2 = 114m of #12 copper.

114m × 0.52Ω / 100m = 0.5928Ω @ 20°C.

Every Amp of current will cause a 0.6V drop of voltage.  This neglects other losses.

1000W 120V capacitor start motor.  \$I_{FLA} =  8.33A\$.

Capacitor start motor can have a starting current of 4-5.75 times run current.

Start current at 4 × = 33.3A, which means a minimum voltage drop of 19.75V.  If you have 120V at inverter, motor could get 100V.  Motor may not start under load.

You have a 1000W motor consuming 207W, which seems wrong.  The motor should *not* get hot, submerged in water.  I'd megger windings to chassis and meter winding resistance because the motor is probably failing due to extensive thermal shutdowns.

Heat kills motors.  Windings use enamel for insulation.  Thermal shutdowns cause increased heat in the windings.  It's there to protect the motor from abuse, but extended thermal shutdowns will cause melting of the enamel, shorting out winding coils.